# Логические операторы в C#, не могу разобраться. Пожалуйста помогите

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xor

Суть в том что если я пенсионер или студент и не трудоустроен, то получаю кредит, а если трудоустроен не получаю кредит.
Ну а если я, и пенсионер и студент,(трудоустройство тут не имеет значения) то не должен получить.
Какие есть способы решить эту задачу, подставил все возможное и что-нибудь да не сходится(
Объясните пожалуйста если не сложно. Спасибо!

```
        Console.Write("Как вас зовут?: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write($"{name} являетесь ли вы пенсионером?: ");
        bool isPensioner = Console.ReadLine().Contains("да");

        Console.Write($"{name} являетесь ли вы студентом?: ");
        bool isStudent = Console.ReadLine().Contains("да");

        Console.Write($"{name} вы уже трудоустроены?: ");
        bool isEmployment = Console.ReadLine().Contains("да");

        bool creditAllowed = isPensioner ^ isStudent ^ isEmployment;

        Console.Write($"{name} имеет право получить кредит: {creditAllowed}");

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: У вас задание про логические операторы, так и используйте логические операторы.

Comment: bool creditAllowed = isPensioner ^ isStudent ^ isEmployment;  <= вот в этом месте не знаю что именно поставить, перепробовал все операторы, кароче  я туплю(

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.24.php

Comment: Вопрос с похожими формулировками, вроде, закрывали совсем недавно - 4-5 дней назад. Что это - задачи из какого то курса по C#?

Comment: Я как-то скачал задачки с какого -то сайте, и вот сижу их решаю) А так параллельно прохожу курсы на youtube, и только начал читать Троелсена)

Comment: Выберите наиболее полезный ответ и отметьте его принятым.

Comment: @aepot ну я вас понял, но у  меня мало репутации чтобы голосовать, как мне отметить более ценный ответ. Я тут совсем недавно и не разобрался еще.

Comment: Вы жмете стрелочки для голосования, а галочка - ниже стрелочек. Вам кстати дадут немного репутации за принятие ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var creditAllowed = (isPensioner ^ isStudent) && !isEmployment;
```

Первой скобкой с оператором `xor` мы проверяем, не является ли у нас человек одновременно студентом и пенсионером, т.к. при `true ^ true` мы получим `false` и кредит не будет выдавать, даже не проверяя трудоустройство, т.к. используется оператор `&&`, который при не выполняет проверку правого выражения, если левое ложно. А оператор `!` мы используем в соответствии с условием.

Comment: разве `пенсионер или студент` соотвествует XOR? ПО мне так это обычное `||`

Comment: @tym32167 ему нужно исключающее ИЛИ, а `||` подойдёт и под условие `пенсионер И студент`

Comment: пенсионер И студет будет как `&&`, я потому вашу логику не могу понять

Comment: `если я пенсионер или студент и не трудоустроен` => `(пенсионер || студент) && !трудоустроен`

Comment: @tym32167 при `||` человек может быть одновременно и студентом и пенсионером и получить кредит, а человек должен быть только кем то одним из них

Comment: `человек должен быть только кем то одним из них` - этого нет в задании же.

Comment: О, стоп, мой косяк ) Увидел

Comment: @tym32167 `Ну а если я, и пенсионер и студент,(трудоустройство тут не имеет значения) то не должен получить`

Answer (score 2):

- ! - логическое **НЕ**
- && - логическое **И**
- ^ - логическое исключающее **ИЛИ** (назовём его **ЛИБО**)

Кредит если (**НЕ** трудоустроен) **И** (пенсионер **ЛИБО** студент):

```
bool creditAllowed = !isEmployment && (isPensioner ^ isStudent);
```